# Is it possible to create a csv export with -Append but overwrite it?

Tags: powershell, append, overwrite, ou

I read out all AD-User out of different OUs.

I Need the function `Append` but if i do it with this it doesn't overwrite the CSV Export if i run the Script again.

If i do it without the function Append it overwrites all other OUs and all I see in the End is the last OU.

My source code:

```
Foreach($OU in $OUs) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties $Properties| Select-Object $Properties |export-Csv -Append $Export -Encoding  UTF8
}
```

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Answer (score 1):

Collect your AD-users in a variable and convert them all together instead of writing to the file `Foreach ($OU in $OUs)`.

```
Foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    $CollectedUsers += Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties $Properties| Select-Object $Properties 
}
$CollectedUsers | export-Csv $Export -Encoding UTF8
```